# json-ld return nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, json-ld

I have the the following json-ld file :

```
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/core#",
    "schema": "http://schema.org/",
    "bd": "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#",
    "data": "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/",
    "owl": "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "fn": "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#",
    "skos": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "align": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/alignment#",
    "dct": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
    "xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace",
    "kb": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/resource/core#",
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    "bds": "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search#",
    "olo": "http://purl.org/ontology/olo/core#",
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "meta": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/resource/metadata#",
    "hint": "http://www.bigdata.com/queryHints#",
    "ebucore": "http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/ontologies/ebucore/ebucore#",
    "igeo": "http://rdf.insee.fr/def/geo#",
    "sesame": "http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#",
    "dc": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  },
  "@graph": [{
      "@id": "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/22/290cf1c7-304b-3fe2-9019-dc1076ff8557",
      "dc:date": {
        "@value": "2019-07-29",
        "@type": "xsd:date"
      },
      "hasContact": [{
          "@id": "data:9baa8a5a-03d1-37f2-b92c-219d7b21ec33",
          "schema:address": {
            "@id": "data:97e95f40-c400-3da7-adc6-3c517556aae2",
            "schema:addressLocality": "Bélaye",
            "schema:postalCode": "46140",
            "schema:streetAddress": "La Tuque",
            "@type": ["schema:PostalAddress","PostalAddress"],
            "hasAddressCity": {
              "@id": "kb:46022"
            }
          },
          "schema:email": "info@campinglatuque.fr",
          "schema:legalName": "Camping la Tuque",
          "@type": ["schema:Organization","foaf:Agent","Agent"],
          "foaf:homepage": "http://www.campinglatuque.fr/"
        },{"@id":"data:d8e8eab2-d298-3fea-bf9f-6eb22a5a5650"}],
      "hasDescription": {
        "@id": "data:c8bb7fc4-aaf6-3a75-bfee-029be952ad88"
      },
      "isLocatedAt": {
        "@id": "data:7f75d9a8-fe40-31d4-b1b4-65c404f140a2",
        "schema:address": {
          "@id": "data:97e95f40-c400-3da7-adc6-3c517556aae2"
        },
        "schema:geo": {
          "@id": "data:47785358-c7ee-35a8-9b47-cf2fcefe11aa",
          "schema:latitude": {
            "@value": "44.4432371",
            "@type": "xsd:decimal"
          },
          "schema:longitude": {
            "@value": "1.1737578",
            "@type": "xsd:decimal"
          },
          "@type": "schema:GeoCoordinates",
          "latlon": {
            "@value": "44.44323#1.17375",
            "@type": "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/geospatial/literals/v1#lat-lon"
          }
        }
      }
  }]
```

and the frame :

```
      "@context": {
       "@vocab":  "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/core#",
       "schema":  "http://schema.org/",
       "bd":      "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#",
       "data":    "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/",
       "owl":     "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
       "xsd":     "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
       "fn":      "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#",
       "skos":    "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
       "rdfs":    "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
       "align":   "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/alignment#",
       "dct":     "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
       "xml":     "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace",
       "kb":      "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/resource/core#",
       "foaf":    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
       "bds":     "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search#",
       "olo":     "http://purl.org/ontology/olo/core#",
       "rdf":     "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
       "meta":    "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/resource/metadata#",
       "hint":    "http://www.bigdata.com/queryHints#",
       "ebucore": "http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/ontologies/ebucore/ebucore#",
       "igeo":    "http://rdf.insee.fr/def/geo#",
       "contains":     {"@id": "http://example.org/vocab#contains", "@type": "@id"},
       "sesame":  "http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#",
       "dc": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
        "PointOfInterest":        "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/core#PointOfInterest"
      },
      "@type": "PointOfInterest",
      "@explicit": "true",
      "hasContact": {
        "schema:address": {
          "@explicit": "true",
          "schema:addressLocality": {},
          "schema:streetAddress": {},
          "hasAddressCity": {
            "@explicit": "true",
            "rdfs:label": {}
          }
        },
        "schema:email": {},
        "schema:telephone": {},
        "schema:legalName": {},
        "schema:familyName": {},
        "schema:givenName": {},
        "foaf:homepage":    {}
      },
       "isLocatedAt": {
          "schema:geo": {
            "@explicit": "true",
            "schema:latitude": {},
            "schema:longitude": {}
          },
          "schema:address": {
            "@explicit": "true",
            "schema:addressLocality": {},
            "schema:streetAddress": {},
            "schema:postalCode": {},
            "hasAddressCity": {
              "@explicit": "true",
              "rdfs:label": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }) )
```

I try to get several information like address, city... but the framing return nil for schema:address

In my loop, I'm trying this :

isLocatedAt = el.dig("isLocatedAt").class => return hash
hasContact  = el.dig("hasContact", "schema:address").class => return hash or nil (if there is and @id)

How can I do for get values like :

address = el.dig("isLocatedAt", "schema:address", "schema:streetAddress")

zip_code = el.dig("isLocatedAt", "schema:address", "schema:postalCode")

city = el.dig("isLocatedAt", "schema:address", "schema:addressLocality")